# Which java-library computes the cumulative standard normal distribution function?

Tags: java, statistics, probability, computation

For a project I have a specification with formulas, I have to implement. In these formulas a cumulative standard normal distribution function exists, that takes a float and outputs a probability. The function is symbolized by a Φ. Exists a Java-library, that computes this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A co-worker suggested [colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/~hoschek/colt/), as he used it before. This [function](http://acs.lbl.gov/~hoschek/colt/api/cern/jet/random/Normal.html#cdf(double)) has exactly the result as the example in the reference document.

Answer (score 14):

[Apache Commons - Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/) has what you are looking for.

More specifically, check out the [`NormalDistribution`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/NormalDistribution.html) class.

Answer (score 8):

If you want the exact code, this one seems to be the same function used in OpenOffice Calc (I've made some changes for it to work in java):

```java
// returns the cumulative normal distribution function (CNDF)
// for a standard normal: N(0,1)
double CNDF(double x)
{
    int neg = (x < 0d) ? 1 : 0;
    if ( neg == 1) 
        x *= -1d;

    double k = (1d / ( 1d + 0.2316419 * x));
    double y = (((( 1.330274429 * k - 1.821255978) * k + 1.781477937) *
                   k - 0.356563782) * k + 0.319381530) * k;
    y = 1.0 - 0.398942280401 * Math.exp(-0.5 * x * x) * y;

    return (1d - neg) * y + neg * (1d - y);
}
```

Found it here: http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2622967/Re-NORMSDIST-function.aspx

Comment: the question wants the pdf of normal distribution!

Comment: I don't think so. The question says "cumulative standard normal distribution function" both in the title and the text ... unless Φ means it's supposed to be the probability density function...

Answer (score 2):

SuanShu, [a Java numerical analysis library](https://nm.dev), computes the normal distribution and many other statistical distributions.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the power series formula, which only takes up about 10 lines of code... see for example http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/22library/Gaussian.java.html (the function `Phi`)