# tensorflow java normal distribution

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, normal-distribution

I need to implement the cumulative distribution function of the normal distribution in Java Tensorflow.

There is a [library function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distributions/Normal) in the python library for Tensorflow Python.

Is there a library function of the normal distribution **in the Java Tensorflow library**? If yes, how can I use it?

Comment: Hello @morvalgo, your question is a bit too broad for me to help you. Have you seen this link: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/package-summary?

Comment: Yes, I have already worked with the Tensorflow Java API, but it does not contain a lot of information. There is no information about distributions. That is why I am not sure if the normal distribution already exists in the Java library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which java-library computes the cumulative standard normal distribution function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442758/which-java-library-computes-the-cumulative-standard-normal-distribution-function)

Comment: You don't need tf for normal cdf

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I want to use Tensorflow for the computation exclusively.